# 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable--working independently but not in for loop

Tags: python, numpy, cluster-analysis

When i write the code as :

```
for i in range(1, k):
        
        idx = np.random.choice(data.shape[0], 1, p=squared_distances/sum(squared_distances))
        
        centroids[i]=data.[idx,:].toarray()
        
        squared_distances=np.min(pairwise_distances(data,centroids[0:i+1],metric='euclidean')**2
```

I get an error as :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-dff0c6ebb89d> in <module>
      1 for i in range(1, k):
      2 
----> 3        idx = np.random.choice(data.shape[0], 1, p=squared_distances/sum(squared_distances))
      4 
      5        centroids[i]=data[idx,:].toarray()

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

But when i run indivisual line:

```
idx = np.random.choice(data.shape[0], 1, p=squared_distances/sum(squared_distances))
```

it gives output as:

```
idx
array([5147])
```

i want to know what is the problem if the code is inside a for loop thats triggering the above given error.

For reference:

```
squared_distances=array([1.99133472, 1.98831716, 1.97838412, ..., 1.97078411, 1.98142071,
       1.99145465])
data.shape=(59071, 547979)
k=3
```

Comment: Your error seems to point to a different variable named `tf_idf_norm`.

Comment: tf_idf_norm is just a 2 d array

Comment: corrected the variable name in the question

Answer (score 0):

The error is produced by `sum(squared_distances)`, which means that at some point `squared_distances` ceases to be a `numpy.ndarray` and becomes `numpy.float64`. Obviously that occurs at `squared_distances = np.min(...)`, because `np.min` by default produces a scalar, calculating the minimum over the whole array. To prevent it you need to supply `np.min` with a correct `axis` argument (`np.min(..., axis=0)` or `np.min(..., axis=1)`) depending on the dimensionality of the `pairwise_distances`'s result.

Comment: thanks a lot . Let me give it a try.@aparpara